# How to find the \textwidth in two-column mode?

Tags: margins, two-column

Sometimes I find that floats don't fit nicely on a page, so I use

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ <blah blah blah> }
```

so that the borders match the margins.  However, I'm now working on a paper in two-column format (specifically using [`sigplanconf.cls`](https://www.sigplan.org/Resources/LaTeXClassFile/)) and if I use the above command, it stretches the table over both columns.

Is there a way I can find the "proper" `\textwidth`? As in, a variable that describes the width of a single column.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try `\columnwidth` as a drop-in replacement for `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 71):

Rather than `\columnwidth`, the appropriate length to use is `\linewidth`, which will either be `\columnwidth` in two-column mode or `\textwidth` in one-column mode.

Comment: In ConTeXt, the value for `\textwidth` seems to take into consideration columns automagically. There appears to be no `\linewidth` value.