# Include hspace in header/footer in fancyhdr?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force a \hspace at the beginning of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/how-can-i-force-a-hspace-at-the-beginning-of-a-line)

I am trying to put a postal address in the footer. I want the first line to be "Address: Address line1", then the next line should start with an indentation or horizontal space so that "Address line2" is aligned just under "Address line1", and so on. I tried:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\scriptsize{\textsf{Address:Address line1\newline\hspace{1in}{Address line2}}}}
```

But the `hspace{}` command is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\scriptsize{\textsf{Address: Address line1\newline\phantom{Address: }{Address line2}}}}
```

`\phantom{<stuff>}` leaves the space required for `<stuff>` without actually typesetting it. That way you're assured things will line up properly.