# How to put two newlines in LaTeX

Tags: line-breaking

How can I put two consecutive newlines in LaTeX? If I put two `\\` the compiler gives me an error.

Comment: You should add the error you are getting. Also there is a speific stackoverflow for Latex.

Comment: It gives me only a question mark, sorry about putting the topic in the wrong place.

Comment: Not sure why you need it. You could use `\\[\baselineskip]`.

Comment: Perhaps this is old behaviour, but four backslashes in a row in a minimal document does not give me an error.  Anyway, `\\` should nearly never be used in text mode, only in special environments.

Answer (score 92):

You can either specify two line breaks with

```
\\~\\
```

or specify the height of the break (for example, for a 2-inch break)

```
\\[2in]
```

You can use this form to define the height of the break to be actually two lines

```
\\[2\baselineskip]
```

See this example: https://www.writelatex.com/read/wtyxrnxxvxhj

Comment: All 3 of your commands work as advertised, but they throw the following messages when using TexMaker and linux command line pdflatex: "Type: Badbox" (the line number it happens on and "Message: Underfull \hbox ..." and these messages seem to appear no matter what type of content occurs before them. Thoughts?

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `\\\\` though? There's still the underfull hbox warning. (the 2 other works.) I think the most likely reason is [spacing - How can I force a \hspace at the beginning of a line? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/how-can-i-force-a-hspace-at-the-beginning-of-a-line)

Answer (score 30):

The “correct” way to do this is adding `\medskip` or `\bigskip`:

```
...
some words that end a paragraph.

\medskip % or \bigskip

Here the new paragraph starts
...
```

Answer (score 10):

You could also type

```
\par\null\par
```