# How to set up the start of the document like this ? (noob here)

Tags: formatting, bookcover

noob here.

I would like to ask you how to make the opening page of the document look like the following picture ? I think everything else would be doable for me without any help as there's only sections, bolds/italics and so forth, the basic stuff. I started writing the most basic LaTeX documents and already I feel a pain when thinking I have to use a WYSIWYG editor.

Can you please give me the input  ? It's things like this that are the biggest hurdle for me to overcome as I wish to fully switch to it once I'm ready - it would be great to do all of my work on it.

Thank you kindly for checking this out.

P.S. The border around the page could be inserted but is unecessary. If it were to be made can you please give me the command to make it appear on all the pages ?

[image]

Comment: "I have to use a WYSIWYG editor."  you mean non-WYSIWYG? Either way it's not really TeX's fault, the "ugly" way (i.e. repeatedly create manual newline or space to "force" the content into the correct position) is very easy (although it's *almost* the *only possible* way in e.g. Word, so you can *choose* to be smarter in TeX.)

Comment: For the ugly way, you do need to know [spacing - How can I force a \hspace at the beginning of a line? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/how-can-i-force-a-hspace-at-the-beginning-of-a-line) and (optionally, to avoid warning)  [line breaking - How to put two newlines in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208442/how-to-put-two-newlines-in-latex) though.

Comment: This should be quite easy. Bur please help us to help you by posting a MWE  that is to say a Minimal (non)-Working Example, (starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`) showing what you have already tried, So that we can copy paste to start with a compilable document which at least contains the text !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic template for your setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

% Add page border
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  % Left rule
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{2em}\rule[2em]{1.5pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-4em}}%
  % Right rule
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2em-1.5pt}\rule[2em]{1.5pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-4em}}%
  % Bottom rule
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{2em}\rule[2em]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4em}{1.5pt}}%
  % Top rule
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{2em}\rule[\dimexpr\paperheight-2em]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4em}{1.5pt}}%
}

\begin{center}
  \large
  Univerzitet u Ni\v{s}u
  
  \bigskip
  
  Filozofski fakultet
  
  \bigskip
  
  Departman za psihologiju
  
  \vfill
  
  \includegraphics[height=7\baselineskip]{example-image}
  
  \vspace{3\bigskipamount}
  
  \textbf{\Huge Anamneza}
  
  \bigskip
  
  {\Large Psihopatologija posebni deo\par}
  
  \vfill
  
  Mentor: Nikola \'{C}irovi\'{c}\hfill
  Student: Danica Lezi\'{c}, 2256

  \vfill
  
  Avgust, 2021, godine
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Tikz solution:

[image: title page]

The border is a separate picture, going into the footer, so appears on every page.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}


\newcommand{\gborder}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw [black, line width=0.8mm]
    ([xshift=2em,yshift=2em]current page.south west)
    rectangle
    ([xshift=-2em,yshift=-2em]current page.north east)
    ;}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[R]{\gborder\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\node (uniname) at ([yshift={\dimexpr0.5\paperheight-8em}]current page.center) {  \large Univerzitet u Nišu};
\node [below=of uniname,yshift=2em] (facname) {\large Filozofski fakultet};
\node [below=of facname,yshift=2em] (deptname) {\large Departman za psihologiju};
\node (cenpage) at (current page.center) {};
\node [above=of cenpage] (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=7\baselineskip]{example-image}};
\node [below=of cenpage] (title) {\textbf{\Huge Anamneza}};
\node [below=of title] (subtitle) {\Large Psihopatologija posebni deo};
\node [below=of subtitle,xshift={\dimexpr-0.5\paperwidth+12em},yshift=-5em] (mentor) {\large Mentor: Nikola Ćirović};
\node [below=of subtitle,xshift={\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-12em},yshift=-5em] (mentor) {\large Student: Danica Lezić, 2256};
\node (dateline) at ([yshift={\dimexpr-0.5\paperheight+8em}]current page.center) {Avgust, 2021, godine};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
x

\newpage

x

\end{document}
```