# Inserting horizontal white space inside item in enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate

I'd like to insert a specific horizontal white space inside an item in enumerate. I tried with \hspace{0.5 cm}, but nothing changes. Can you tell me how to reach this goal please?

---

EDIT: the second "hello" should be shifted 0.5 cm to the right

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello
    \\
    \hspace{0.5 cm} hello
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a sketch of what you want? At the moment it is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to updated question

You have several options, including:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \\
    \hspace*{0.5 cm} it's me
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \\
    \mbox{}\hspace{0.5 cm} can you hear me
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \\
    \null\hspace{0.5 cm} from the outside
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \\
    \hbox{}\hspace{0.5 cm} how are you?
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item hello \\
    \vbox{}\hspace{0.5 cm} from the other side
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

See also e.g. [How can I force a \hspace at the beginning of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/how-can-i-force-a-hspace-at-the-beginning-of-a-line)

I don't know about the ins and outs of these, but there's other questions for that on here answered by more knowledgeable people than me. Sorry for my previous somewhat rude answer, and all the best! :-)

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Previous Answer

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[please \hspace{0.5cm} include] \hspace{0.5cm} MWE
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much @steve, i did a mistake in the code.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Don't worry, just for next time ;-)

Comment: Hi @steve, i edited my question; now the problem should be clearer.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you for your help.