# How can I anchor TikZ matrix cell contents to 'baseline' without shifting cell location?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

The cells in my tables often contain expressions with superscripts. This results in a text baseline that appears to "wander" between adjacent cells. For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=7mm}]
\matrix{
    \node[fill=gray!10]{$a$};  &  \node[fill=gray!20]{$a^2$};  &  \node[fill=gray!30]{$b$}; &  \node[fill=gray!40]{$b^2$}; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

I understand that the way to align the text of all cells to a common baseline is to use `anchor=base`, but this has the side effect of jumbling the cells. For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,minimum size=7mm}]
\matrix{
    \node[fill=gray!10]{$a$};  &  \node[fill=gray!20]{$a^2$};  &  \node[fill=gray!30]{$b$}; &  \node[fill=gray!40]{$b^2$}; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

Is there a way to align all text to a common baseline, without shifting the cells as well?

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=7mm}]
\matrix{
    \node[fill=gray!10]{$a$};  &  \node[fill=gray!20]{$a^2$};  &  \node[fill=gray!30]{$b$}; &  \node[fill=gray!40]{$b^2$}; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,minimum size=7mm}]
\matrix{
    \node[fill=gray!10]{$a$};  &  \node[fill=gray!20]{$a^2$};  &  \node[fill=gray!30]{$b$}; &  \node[fill=gray!40]{$b^2$}; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may fix height *and* depth of text:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,
    text height=.8em,text depth=.2em,minimum size=7mm}]
  \matrix{
    \node[fill=gray!10]{$a$};&
    \node[fill=gray!20]{$a^2$};&
    \node[fill=gray!30]{$b$}; &
    \node[fill=gray!40]{$b^2$};\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Fixing depth of text is necessary for letters like 'g' or 'y'...

Comment: What do you say about Will's answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex ? Should we change it to `2ex` ? ;)

Comment: @percusse I usually use only `em` mainly because ratio between `ex` and `em` are often the same regardless of the chosen font...

Comment: @PolGab Haha, I do exactly the same.

Comment: @percusse: another justification to prefer `em` instead of `ex` was given by Will himself: "I usually consider `1em` to be about the same size as the font size in points." ;-)

Comment: Perhaps better is `  \matrix[every node/.style =...` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style =...`.

Comment: Can't be this done somehow automatically, i.e. not guessing the values and instead use minimal needed for the particular content?

Comment: @user87690 Which particular content? All matrix nodes? IMHO, appropriate values depend on the semantic of node's content.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: It could be possible to specify the set of nodes. It would be nice to be able to say "make baselines and heights, possibly widths of these nodes the same" without explicitely specifying the sizes.

Comment: @user87690 Ok. Ask a new question...