# Set the length of 1ex

Tags: lengths

How can I set the length of `1ex`? I tried `\setlength{1ex}{4.40999pt}` but I get errors.

Comment: `ex` is a font-dependent unit of measurement. See [Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex) and [What are the various units (ex, in, pt, etc.) expressed in mm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm)

Comment: ... and what exactly do you need it for? Maybe there is some other way than changing `1ex` which is really impossible.

Comment: Are you trying to change the font size?

Comment: shouldn't it be enough to set `\fontdimen5` to some value?

Comment: @PatrickGundlach You can change a `\fontdimen` only when the font has just been loaded into memory. With LaTeX it's very difficult unless the font is loaded before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Glad I learn something new everyday. Thanks @egreg.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure what you mean. A quick test suggests you can alter `\fontdimen5`. Whether it's a good idea is another thing entirely.

Comment: @JosephWright You're right, indeed; I mistook the feature for *adding* font dimension parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: ex is a font dependant value and you change it by changing `\fontdimen5`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
a\hspace{1ex}b

\fontdimen5\font=1cm
a\hspace{1ex}b

\fontdimen5\font=2cm
a\hspace{1ex}b

\bfseries 
a\hspace{1ex}b 

\normalfont
a\hspace{1ex}b

\large
a\hspace{1ex}b

\small
a\hspace{1ex}b

\end{document}
```