# canonical units for defining white space in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, spacing, units

When using `\hspace` and `\vspace`, I often run into a decision of which units to use. In many examples I see the use of `ex`, `cm`, `mm`, `pt`, `in`, and so on. I also use `.1\textwidth` or `.1\textheight`. I wonder if there is a standard unit that makes sense for moving boxes or figures in beamer; I am recently consolidating all of my vertical space units to `ex` but is this sensible? Is there an equivalent horizontal space unit which corresponds to character width (for a monospace font), for instance?

Comment: You can use `em` for horizontal space. See this for more info: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm ,especially Herbert's last answer and this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex

Comment: Some units change depending on the type size. For example, if your `\documentclass` has a `10pt` (`11pt`) option then `1em` will be equal to `10pt` (`11pt`). Some lengths are better expressed relative to the type size, in which case you should use `em` or `ex`. Other units are better expressed in absolute units such as `cm`, `m`, and even `inch`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends *why* you are moving things.

`.1\textwidth` is a fraction of the page size so changes if you change page size (which is perhaps less likely in beamer than in a journal article class). `5pt` is a fixed unit (at some notional size which may not relate to any actual size by the time you have projected your presentation, so it is more or less used the same way as a fraction of `\textwidth` for positioning things relative to the page in fixed units. `cm`, `in` etc are just (in TeX) defined as fixed multiples of `pt` so they are just for human convenience. If you find `cm` more convenient than `pt` use it if not, don't.

`ex` and `em` are *font* related sizes so don't use them for positioning on page as the position will change depending on the font. Use them for things like indents (or defining the size of inter-word-space) or inter-paragraph space where the size determination relates to the content rather than the area into which the content is being typeset.

Traditionally `em` is used for horizontal units (its name derives from the width of an `M`) and `ex` is used for vertical units (its name derives from the height of an `x`).