# How to position letters *exactly* above each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, letters

I'm trying to stack bold capital letters, like in the example below. There should be no white space between letters and letters also should not overlap. Some letters should be stretched tall or short.

As far as I can tell, TikZ does not distinguish between bold and regular style, and between letters that are minimally taller than others (e.g., `C` vs `E`).

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Should I not be using TikZ at all? I would like to avoid manually adjusting each letter's y-position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document} 
\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}[mytext/.style = {inner sep=0, outer sep=0}, font=\bfseries] 
  \node (c1) [mytext, anchor=south] at (0,0) {C};
  \node (c2) [mytext, above=0 of c1, color=red] {C};
  \node      [mytext, above=0 of c2] {E};
  \node (c3) [mytext, yscale=2, anchor=south] at (1,0) {C};
  \node (c4) [mytext, yscale=0.5, above=0 of c3, color=red] {C};
  \node      [mytext, yscale=0.5, above=0 of c4] {E};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tikz (latex) doesn't see the ink of the glyphs, only their bounding box and the C sticks a bit outside of the box. This is a decision of the font designer.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you stack two A's? Do you want them to be verti-kerned together so that the tip of the lower one touches the bar of the top one? If so, I think you're going to have to go through every pair of glyphs you use in your font manually.

Comment: @user2357112, There can be whitespace between the bar of the upper `A` and the top of the lower `A`.

Comment: This answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381, and this link, https://ilovetypography.com/2009/01/14/inconspicuous-vertical-metrics/, may be helpful in explaining why there is no easy answer to your question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

TeX does not know the shape of the glyphs. It only knows the character box dimensions as specified in the TFM file.

### Font identification

The font files can be identified the following way:

- Use a document with just this font, for example, the document of the question is fine, if `\pagestyle{empty}` is added.
- Run it through `pdflatex` with option `-recorder`.
- The end part of the log file and the `*.fls` file reveals `cmbx12.pfb` as the font.
- The font metrics can only be seen in the recorder file `*.fls`:

  ```
  INPUT cmbx12.tfm
  ```

### Font shape data

Open the glyph shapes in a font editor like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/).
The trim margins:

```
C: 62 -12 63 -12 (width 812)
E: 38   0 32   5 (width 738)
```

The font also tells that 1em = 1000 units

### TeX metrics

The binary `*.tfm` file can be converted to ASCII in a better readable format by the program `tftopl`:

```
tftopl cmbx12.pfb cmbx12.pl
```

It contains at the beginning the font dimension parameters:

```
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.375)
   (STRETCH R 0.1875)
   (SHRINK R 0.125)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.444444)
   (QUAD R 1.125)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.125)
   )
```

The entry `QUAD` specifies the size of 1em. It is 1.125 of the font em size.

The character metrics are quite the same as in the font (except for some kind of "rounding" issues):

```
(CHARACTER C C
   (CHARWD R 0.8125)
   (CHARHT R 0.686111)
   )
...
(CHARACTER C E
   (CHARWD R 0.738426)
   (CHARHT R 0.686111)
   )
```

The width for C is 0.8125 * multiplied with the em size of the font = 812.5 font units. Truncated to integer, this are the 812 that FontForge has shown.

The following example defines some macros to specifiy the trim values for the glyph and defines macro `\GlyphBox` that fixes its TeX box to fit the glyph exactly (except rounding issues).

To keep the macros only work for one font. They can be extended to add another argument for the font name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\EmSize}[1]{%
  \def\@EmSize{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@GlyphPropName}[2]{%
  GS@#1@#2%
}
\newcommand*{\GlyphProp}[2]{%
  \@nameuse{\@GlyphPropName{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand*{\GlyphSize}[5]{%
  \@namedef{\@GlyphPropName{#1}{llx}}{#2}%
  \@namedef{\@GlyphPropName{#1}{lly}}{#3}%
  \@namedef{\@GlyphPropName{#1}{urx}}{#4}%
  \@namedef{\@GlyphPropName{#1}{ury}}{#5}%
}
\newcommand*{\GlyphBox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{%
      \kern-\dimexpr1em*\GlyphProp{#1}{llx}/\@EmSize\relax
      #1%
      \kern-\dimexpr1em*\GlyphProp{#1}{urx}/\@EmSize\relax
    }%
    \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 - 1em*\GlyphProp{#1}{ury}/\@EmSize\relax
    \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0 - 1em*\GlyphProp{#1}{lly}/\@EmSize\relax
    \box0\relax
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
% Font cmbx12
\EmSize{1125}% 1000 units in font, 1.125 in TFM
\GlyphSize{C}{62}{-12}{63}{-12}
\GlyphSize{E}{38}{0}{32}{5}

\begin{document} 
\Huge
\bfseries

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}
\textcolor{red}{%
  \fbox{\color{black}\GlyphBox{C}}%
  \fbox{\color{black}\GlyphBox{E}}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mytext/.style = {inner sep=0, outer sep=0}, font=\bfseries]
  \node (c1) [mytext, anchor=south] at (0,0) {\GlyphBox{C}};
  \node (c2) [mytext, above=0 of c1, color=red] {\GlyphBox{C}};
  \node      [mytext, above=0 of c2] {\GlyphBox{E}};
  \node (c3) [mytext, yscale=2, anchor=south] at (1,0) {\GlyphBox{C}};
  \node (c4) [mytext, yscale=0.5, above=0 of c3, color=red] {\GlyphBox{C}};
  \node      [mytext, yscale=0.5, above=0 of c4] {\GlyphBox{E}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I like your answer a lot. Two questions: (1) Is there perhaps a reference missing to `lly` in `\GlyphBox`? (2) What is the best way to get trim margins in FontForge? (Off topic: `pdfcrop` has been incredibly useful to me. Thanks!)

Comment: @FrankSeifert (1) Thanks, there was a typo (`ury` instead of `lly`). (2) I had done it manually for the two characters.  But FontForge can also be scripted, e.g. it has an interface for Python 2.

Answer (score 11):

xelatex

[image]

pdflatex

[image]

15 more characters

Comment: Bad boy, you are cheating. Very likely your XeLaTeX run loads package `fontspec` and uses a different font: Latin Modern in OpenType format vs. Computer Modern in Type1 with TFM.

Comment: Horizontally, it will not work, because the side bearings are kept.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek true although my original idea was to use `XeTeXglyphbounds` to adjust things before I remembered it wan't needed here but that could be used to adjust the horizontal sidebearings as well, without needing to edit the font.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek about the cheating true but I did check that using latin modern rather than cm with pdflatex didn't make any real difference here (although that isn't the same latin modern as pdftex uses of course) (and no it did not use fontspec it was exactly the OPs example file)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get overlaps with XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 and font "CMBX12" with type "Type 1C" (reported by `pdffonts`). If I add `\usepackage{fontspec}`, the overlap is gone, but the font is "LMRoman12-Bold-Identity-H" with type "CID Type 0C".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek sure, if you use cm, but unless your xelatex is old, it will default to TU encoding and opentype latin modern fonts, I used the document in the question unchanged.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you  need a hammersledge like  `tikz` for this: a simple   `tabular`, the `\scalebox` command and the `\Gape` command from `makecell` for a  precise adjustment, will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, graphicx}

\newcommand{\vscalebox}[2][1]{\scalebox{1}[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\Huge}c}
E\\ \Gape[0.3pt]{\color{red}C}\\ \Gape[0.3pt]{C}
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\Huge}c}
\vscalebox[0.5]{E}\\ \Gape[0.15pt]{\vscalebox[0.5]{\color{red}C}}\\ \Gape[0.6pt]{\vscalebox[2]{C}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with Metafun.

```
\setupbodyfont[10pt]
\starttext
\setbox0=\hbox{\bf C}
\newdimen\dpC \dpC=\dp0
\startMPpage
picture E; E := image ( draw outlinetext ("\bf E") ) ;
picture Ca; Ca := image ( draw outlinetext.f ("\bf C") (withcolor red) ) ;
picture Cb; Cb := image ( draw outlinetext ("\bf C") ) ;
currentpicture := E;
addto currentpicture also Ca
    shifted (0,-bbheight Ca+\the\dpC);
addto currentpicture also Cb
    shifted (0,-bbheight Ca-bbheight Cb+\the\dpC);
\stopMPpage
\startMPpage
picture E; E := image ( draw outlinetext ("\bf E") yscaled (.5) ) ;
picture Ca; Ca := image ( draw outlinetext.f ("\bf C") (withcolor red) yscaled (.5) ) ;
picture Cb; Cb := image ( draw outlinetext ("\bf C") yscaled (2) ) ;
currentpicture := E;
addto currentpicture also Ca
    shifted (0,-bbheight Ca+.5*\the\dpC);
addto currentpicture also Cb
    shifted (0,-bbheight Ca-bbheight Cb+2*\the\dpC);
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

[image]