# determine current font height

Tags: fonts, height

There are many answers here which explain how to obtain the *size* of the current *font* (`\f@size`) and others which explain how to obtain the *height* of a given *character* (`\settoheight`) in the current font.

I would like to know how to obtain the *height* of a *font*, i.e. the distance between the upper edge of the enclosing box of a capital letter and the baseline. Is there such a metric defined for fonts, i.e. is there such a property within font design? – The idea is motivated by the graphic in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275381/38399) that the letters "Q" and "A" (at least in that font, at least to the precision of the rendering) have the same height.

If not, is there a "typical" capital letter whose height could be used as a substitute?

Background: I'm trying to align a TikZ text node with respect to its upper edge, but the actual text can vary depending on the circumstances and may or may not contain capital letters. The idea would be to position using the baseline instead, and set the coordinate lower by a certain amount.

Comment: Could you give a MWE to show what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck, I'm looking for a generic answer, not the solution to a concrete programming problem. I added the "Background" only for motivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way `fontspec` determines `Scale=MatchUppercase` is exactly how you said in your question.  It measures the height of the letter `H`, which you can do with `\settoheight`.  The H-height is a traditional way of doing it (I’ve also seen T), but some fonts might have an ornament on the letter H that makes a different letter a better choice.

If you want to measure the descent, you could take the depth of `gjpqy`.  This will give you the greatest depth of any of them.

Comment: Thanks, if `fontspec` does it this way, that's good enough for me. – For future reference for people who want to achieve something similar: I ended up using `node[anchor=base,yshift=-height("H")]`; `height` is TikZ' shorter version of `\settoheight`.

Comment: Sorry, follow-up: Is there a similar letter recommendation for a "typical" descender depth? E.g. "y" or "g"?

Comment: @A.Donda It depends on the font; in Computer Modern the deepest glyph is j, but for other fonts it could be y. Also, the height depends on the language: with French, for instance, you should also take into account accents.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement [Davislor's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553617/38399), according to fonts.com, the "font height" I was asking for is typographically called *cap(ital) height*, or [*H height*](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/glossary/h#H%20height). The corresponding "font depth" is called *descender depth* or [*p height*](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/glossary/p#p-height). And finally, there is the *ascender height* or [*k height*](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/glossary/k#k-height).
All terms reflect the letters typically used to define them.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height) states that the cap height is determined from capital letters with a flat top such as "H" or "I".