# How to measure the width of a character including overshoot

Tags: boxes, characters, bounding-box

I'm trying to measure the width of arbitrary letters. For example, I'm using this to get the width of a letter A:

```tex
\settowidth{\letterwidth}{A}
```

This seems to work fine for all my letters, *except* for the letter Q, where the tail overshoots the box. I can see this with a framebox:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{Q}

\end{document}
```

Running this through [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/htdqyjntwgqf) produces a Q whose tail slightly overflows the box:

[image]

(Note that this example isn't super pronounced, because I was trying to use a built-in font that replicates the issue, but it's far more pronounced with the particular custom font I'm using).

How do I reliably draw a box around the *whole* character, including overshoot?

Comment: This isn't a "problem", it is a "feature".  It occurs on the vertical extent of the letters all the time.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381.  It even has a name: "overshoot": https://ilovetypography.com/2009/01/14/inconspicuous-vertical-metrics/. It has to do with human perception, and yes, it does pose a challenge for finding a box that surrounds the printed glyph.

Comment: I never thought it was a "problem" per se; I just want to know how to get the "true" width of the rendered glyph

Comment: I was being a bit facetious in my reply, which is why I "air-quoted" the words.  Sorry.

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX?

Comment: @egreg LuaLaTeX