# Accurately aligning a letter top to the top of the page

Tags: tex-core

I do not understand why I am not succeeding in accurately aligning the top of a capital letter to the top of the page. I am experimenting with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\parskip=0mm
\topmargin=-1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\topskip=0pt
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

And the top of the letter 'A' goes slightly out of the page (by approximately -0.33pt), namely you miss the top serif. This is also quite visible using a pdf editor that tells you the exact top position of any graphical element on the page.

Any hint?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381  Overshoot protrusion relates to how visual perception detects 'balance' of a shape.

Comment: Yeah the answer linked by @Cicada above is the answer to this question as well. TeX is told (by the font metrics) that the capital letter A in this font has a height of 6.83331pt (or in TeX's scaled points 447828sp), so it places the "A" at 6.83331pt from the top of the page (in this example). TeX only works with font metrics, and has no knowledge that the font designer (also originally Knuth, in the case of Computer Modern) has chosen to have the capital A have an "overshoot" beyond the declared box dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is thus to actually measure the height of what you need to type out when for decorative purposes or to obey a design you need to perfectly vertically touch something.