# How do I convert pt/in/cm/mm to em/ex as they are defined at a given point in the document?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I am using various macros that I have fine-tuned with units like `pt` and `cm`. I use those macros normally in certain places (say, in main body text or in footnote text). To properly generalize those macros, I would like to replace the absolute units by relative ones.

Say I have a macro `\newcommand*{\aalso}{\textsl{and also}\hspace{1.1pt}}`. Say I normally use that macro in footnotes. But now I realize that I made a mistake and would like to change the length `1.1pt` to something of the form `...em` so that I can use the macro elsewhere. How do I get the right number? I assume that the right way is to define some macro like `\emConverter{1.1pt}` that, if issued in a footnote context, gives me the length of `1.1pt` in a footnote context converted to a relative length in `em`. It doesn't need to be a LaTeX-parsable value; it's okay if this is just printed out directly into the document, for me to then manually write the new `em`-value into the source code.

Some relevant questions:

- [What are the various units (ex, in, pt, etc.) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/14996)
- [Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4239/14996)

Comment: Since you are willing to do it manually you can just use the conversion table given in [What are the various units (ex, in, pt, etc.) expressed in mm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm). Once those are converted to `em`, `ex` they should be correct independent of if they are in the footnote. I don't think it makes sense to convert based on the actual footnote value as then they won't scale if the fonts are changed.

Comment: See for example output of `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
In text \verb|\hspace*{1.0em}| is x\hspace*{1.0em}x.
\footnote{In footnote this space is smaller: x\hspace*{1.0em}x.}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill The tables contain too many variables so that for someone not wanting to bother looking up font internals the tables are a risk. *Because* these values are context-dependent and I have fine-tuned them *in some very specific contexts*, I'd just like a macro that tells me the right value directly (under my assumption that my fine-tuned values will sensibly scale if I replace them by (say) an `em`-value that is exactly right in the original context where I fine-tuned the (say) `pt`-value).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\convertto}{mm}
    % #1 = em or ex (or any other unit)
    % #2 = dimen to convert
 {
  \texttt{#2~=~\fp_to_decimal:n { (#2)/(1#1) }#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\convertto{em}{1.1pt}

\convertto{ex}{1.1pt}

\Large
\convertto{em}{1.1pt}

\convertto{ex}{1.1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant for also showing a given length (explicit or implicit) in a different unit of measure (default `mm`); I also added rounding to five digits

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\convertto}{mm}
    % #1 = em or ex (or any other unit)
    % #2 = dimen to convert
 {
  \texttt{#2~=~\fp_to_decimal:n { round ( (#2)/(1#1), 5 ) }#1}
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\thelength}{ O{mm} m }
 {
  \fp_to_decimal:n { round ( #2/1#1, 5 ) } #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\convertto{em}{1.1pt}

\convertto{ex}{1.1pt}

\Large
\convertto{em}{1.1pt}

\convertto{ex}{1.1pt}

\thelength{\textwidth}

\thelength[cm]{\textwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An example application; we want to modify the output of `layout` so that it uses millimeters. We need only `\thelength`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{layout}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\thelength}{ O{mm} m }
 {
  \fp_to_decimal:n { round ( (#2)/(1#1), 5 ) } #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% redefine the output macro
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{\thelength{\csname #2\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

I only show the relevant part of the output, with the lengths

[image]

Comment: To everyone: **See also Paul Gaborit's correct answer.**

Answer (score 19):

You can use `pgfmath` to compute the conversion:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\len{1.1pt/1em}
```

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=6cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\pttoem[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\len{#1pt/1em}Here, with the current font, #1\,pt is
  \len{}\,em.
}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\texttt{\pttoem{1.1}} \textbf{\pttoem{1.1}}
\pttoem{1.1}\footnote{\pttoem{1.1}}

{\large \pttoem{1.1}\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to compile your code exactly, and I get an "Undefined control sequence" error for `\pgfkeys`. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: @LoverofStructure With CTAN version of pgf, replace `\usepackage{pgfmath}` by `\usepackage{pgf}`.

Comment: I just tried and can hereby confirm that this works; thanks!

Comment: By the way, loading `pgfcore` (instead of `pgf`) suffices in my case.