# To display the lengths in millimeters by default

Tags: lengths

All my length are in millimetres and the command \the\mylength outputs a length in points.
Idem with the \layout from the package `layout`.

How can I display all theses lengths in millimetres (more easily understandable than the points).

Comment: You can't do it with `\the` unless you change the source code of TeX and recompile it. There are other questions dealing with the problem of showing length in different units of measure.

Comment: @egreg: The duplicate does not explain, how to reconfigure package `layout`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I'll add it as an example application.

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to convert a dimen with unit `pt` to another unit such as `mm`, see [How do I convert pt/in/cm/mm to em/ex as they are defined at a given point in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99550/16967), for example.

The following document prints the layout values of package `layout`'s `\layout` in mm using e-TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is the number 0.351459 a conversion factor purely? because google says 1 pt=0.352778 mm.

Comment: @kaka TeX's pt: 1 in = 2.54 mm = 72.27 pt, conversion factor = 0.351459. TeX's bp = 1 in = 2.54mm = 72 bp, conversion factor = 0.352778. The points in PostScript or PDF are TeX's bp. TeX uses the slightly smaller points as unit for displaying lengths.

Comment: thanks for sharing that. I had no idea about that.