# Declaring option a4paper in \documentclass produces different margins than declaring it in \geometry

Tags: document-classes, geometry, best-practices, paper-size, package-options

I have seen a similar question at [a4paper, where should I declare it? In document class or geometry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62311) and the selected answer there implies that there is no difference in whether we use `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` or if we use `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}`.

But my observations contradict the selected answer there.

Here is my code in file `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec
lobortis justo. Praesent ut scelerisque risus, sit amet mollis erat.
Fusce at lacus at libero consequat consectetur.

Proin at vehicula ligula. Vivamus quis ligula id lacus aliquet
ultricies. Vivamus tristique, velit vestibulum tincidunt fermentum,
lacus sem euismod risus, ut volutpat augue dolor vitae est. Proin odio
nunc, sollicitudin quis nisi a, sodales efficitur quam. Phasellus ex
velit, porttitor vestibulum consectetur eu, maximus et nisi.

Nulla pharetra augue ex, quis scelerisque sem iaculis id. Aliquam in
tincidunt quam. Praesent ac laoreet elit. Aenean varius ullamcorper
dolor ac finibus. Proin est sapien, tempor nec mollis ut, ultricies et
ante. Maecenas hendrerit velit non augue rutrum, mollis pharetra nisl
auctor. Ut nisl mauris, porta ut nisi ut, elementum tristique nibh. 
\end{document}
```

Here is another one in file `bar.tex`. The only thing that is different here is the usage of `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` instead of `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec
lobortis justo. Praesent ut scelerisque risus, sit amet mollis erat.
Fusce at lacus at libero consequat consectetur.

Proin at vehicula ligula. Vivamus quis ligula id lacus aliquet
ultricies. Vivamus tristique, velit vestibulum tincidunt fermentum,
lacus sem euismod risus, ut volutpat augue dolor vitae est. Proin odio
nunc, sollicitudin quis nisi a, sodales efficitur quam. Phasellus ex
velit, porttitor vestibulum consectetur eu, maximus et nisi.

Nulla pharetra augue ex, quis scelerisque sem iaculis id. Aliquam in
tincidunt quam. Praesent ac laoreet elit. Aenean varius ullamcorper
dolor ac finibus. Proin est sapien, tempor nec mollis ut, ultricies et
ante. Maecenas hendrerit velit non augue rutrum, mollis pharetra nisl
auctor. Ut nisl mauris, porta ut nisi ut, elementum tristique nibh.
\end{document}
```

But the output from both files are different. Here is a side by side comparison with `foo.pdf` on left and `bar.pdf` on right.

> [image] [image]

I have three questions:

- Why are the two outputs different? Looks like it is due to different margins. Am I right?
- Do these outputs contradict the selected answer at [a4paper, where should I declare it? In document class or geometry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62311) ?
- Is there a best practice regarding where `a4paper` should be declared?

Comment: What is your default document setting when you installed, say, TeX Live? Was it set to `letterpaper` or `a4paper`?

Comment: @Werner `letterpaper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geometry` changes the layout (unless you use the option pass).

So there is a difference between documents with `geometry` and documents without `geometry`.

But if you load geometry it doesn't make a difference if you set `a4paper` with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

or with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the clearest way to see the differences is to use package `layout` showing you the current writing area and margins and several length of the document in mm.

Please see this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{layout}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173244/to-display-the-lengths-in-millimeters-by-default
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec
lobortis justo. Praesent ut scelerisque risus, sit amet mollis erat.
Fusce at lacus at libero consequat consectetur.

Proin at vehicula ligula. Vivamus quis ligula id lacus aliquet
ultricies. Vivamus tristique, velit vestibulum tincidunt fermentum,
lacus sem euismod risus, ut volutpat augue dolor vitae est. Proin odio
nunc, sollicitudin quis nisi a, sodales efficitur quam. Phasellus ex
velit, porttitor vestibulum consectetur eu, maximus et nisi.

Nulla pharetra augue ex, quis scelerisque sem iaculis id. Aliquam in
tincidunt quam. Praesent ac laoreet elit. Aenean varius ullamcorper
dolor ac finibus. Proin est sapien, tempor nec mollis ut, ultricies et
ante. Maecenas hendrerit velit non augue rutrum, mollis pharetra nisl
auctor. Ut nisl mauris, porta ut nisi ut, elementum tristique nibh. 
\clearpage
\layout
\end{document}
```

and the resulting layout:

[image]

Now please compare the result above with this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173244/to-display-the-lengths-in-millimeters-by-default
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec
lobortis justo. Praesent ut scelerisque risus, sit amet mollis erat.
Fusce at lacus at libero consequat consectetur.

Proin at vehicula ligula. Vivamus quis ligula id lacus aliquet
ultricies. Vivamus tristique, velit vestibulum tincidunt fermentum,
lacus sem euismod risus, ut volutpat augue dolor vitae est. Proin odio
nunc, sollicitudin quis nisi a, sodales efficitur quam. Phasellus ex
velit, porttitor vestibulum consectetur eu, maximus et nisi.

Nulla pharetra augue ex, quis scelerisque sem iaculis id. Aliquam in
tincidunt quam. Praesent ac laoreet elit. Aenean varius ullamcorper
dolor ac finibus. Proin est sapien, tempor nec mollis ut, ultricies et
ante. Maecenas hendrerit velit non augue rutrum, mollis pharetra nisl
auctor. Ut nisl mauris, porta ut nisi ut, elementum tristique nibh. 
\clearpage
\layout
\end{document}
```

and its result (`[a4paper]` is option of package `geometry`):

[image]

You see the different length for `\textheight` and `\textwidth`? At last that means that `geometry` uses different standard margins than class `article` without `geometry`.

Now have please a look to this code, having option `[a4paper]` only placed as class option for `article`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173244/to-display-the-lengths-in-millimeters-by-default
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec
lobortis justo. Praesent ut scelerisque risus, sit amet mollis erat.
Fusce at lacus at libero consequat consectetur.

Proin at vehicula ligula. Vivamus quis ligula id lacus aliquet
ultricies. Vivamus tristique, velit vestibulum tincidunt fermentum,
lacus sem euismod risus, ut volutpat augue dolor vitae est. Proin odio
nunc, sollicitudin quis nisi a, sodales efficitur quam. Phasellus ex
velit, porttitor vestibulum consectetur eu, maximus et nisi.

Nulla pharetra augue ex, quis scelerisque sem iaculis id. Aliquam in
tincidunt quam. Praesent ac laoreet elit. Aenean varius ullamcorper
dolor ac finibus. Proin est sapien, tempor nec mollis ut, ultricies et
ante. Maecenas hendrerit velit non augue rutrum, mollis pharetra nisl
auctor. Ut nisl mauris, porta ut nisi ut, elementum tristique nibh. 
\clearpage
\layout
\end{document}
```

and its result. You see it is the same result in length we have after using option `[a4paper]` only with `geometry`:

[image]

So the conclusion is to use option `a4paper` as class option, because all other packages get noticed about this option, if it is related to them ...

Class `article` uses other standard margins than `geometry`, that's the reason for the  differences you get.

Comment: I think my question is relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524987/proper-way-to-switch-paper-size .  Feel free to take a look if you have time.

Answer (score 3):

The outputs are different because [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) updates the *layout* (stock margins) in addition to the page size. In contrast, loading a document class like `article` with `a4paper` only changes the paper dimensions. See [Default margins for geometry package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44850/5764).

Here's the only changes imposed by [`\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co):

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
```

I prefer to load any geometry-related settings with the package since that's what you're loading it for. That is, using the following sequence:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  % <geometry settings>
}
```