# Figure structuring made easy?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, displaystyle

Is there any online tool or an easy way of structuring figures in LaTeX? For example, imagine I want to do something like

[image]

labelled like that.

It somehow seems unnecessarily tricky to get something like this, while I could quickly draw it in Word, for example. Any recommendations?

Comment: As  another option, for making a layout  of any king of material in a page see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576386/161015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any package that can do this. However, it is not that hard constructing this using `minipage`s and `subfigure`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth, height=1.7cm]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure b}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure c}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure e}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Subfigure f}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: structured figures]