Keeping units without reverse converting
In this example, I have several units, all of them are converted to pts.
Is it possible to keep the units, without reverse converting?
\newdimen\test
Unit em: \test=5em
\the\test

Unit cm: \test=5cm
\the\test

Unit in: \test=5in \divide \test by 2
\the\test

\bye


\dimen registers always use pt (actually sp where 1pt=65536 sp).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99550/how-do-i-convert-pt-in-cm-mm-to-em-ex-as-they-are-defined-at-a-given-point-in-th

dimen registers are integer variables interpreted as scaled points, there is no record of the units used originally.
If you need to store a value and a unit, use a macro not a register.
Unit em: \def\test{5em}
\test

Unit cm: \def\test{5cm}
\test


\bye

For the division you have a choice to use dimen arithmetic directly and lose the units or you can use a more complicated processing eg remove the last two letters, do the division using pt then restore the original unit
