# How to make a symbol adjust its size globally and locally

Tags: dimensions

In the following code I have created a bullseye symbol. What I want to do is to allow its size to change dynamically both globally (document class option say 10pt, 11pt or 12pt) or locally by using `\small`, `\large`, and any command that declares size. That is if in the options of the document class you have `10pt` as an option then the symbol will have a size of `10pt` if used in the document unless enclosed in `{\small}` or the sort in which case its size will adjust dynamically to the document settings.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bullseye}{%
\tikz{%
\filldraw (0,0) circle (0.6em);
\filldraw[white] (0,0) circle (0.4em);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (0.2em);
}
}
\begin{document}
{\small\bullseye  sample text} sample text % as you can see no change.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `.6em`, `.4em` and `.2em`

Comment: Yeah @egreg since it is a horizontal length working with `em` is better as it is with `ex` with height right?

Comment: There's no rule for this. Use the one that gives the best results; it mostly depends on how you want the symbol to stick above the baseline with respect to the surrounding text (`ex`) or you prefer the horizontal dimension (`em`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use font dependent units instead of pt

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bullseye}{%
\tikz{%
\filldraw (0,0) circle (.6em);
\filldraw[white] (0,0) circle (.4em);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (.2em);
}
}
\begin{document}
{\small\bullseye  sample text} sample text % as you can see no change.


{\bullseye  sample text} sample text % as you can see no change.


{\large\bullseye  sample text} sample text % as you can see no change.

\end{document}
```

Comment: dependent on what?

Comment: Say the font size is set to 10pt for the document, is it possible to make the size(height) of the symbol be that without manually setting it?

Comment: in that case 1em at \normalsize will be 10pt so just use em units and it will size with [10pt] or [12pt] document options

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: 1em and 1ex does _not only_ change with _fontsize_, but also with family, weight and shape. See my survey made as an answer to “<http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex/97970#97970>”.

Comment: @Johan_E yes of course they are font parameters so can be set to any values by the font designer, but in the context of this question size is the important feature and if you define in em units the symbol will change with both font size changes like `\large` and document options like `[12pt]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; sure. The comment was only to remind of the other factors that `1em` and `1ex` may depend on; so they don’t come back and bite you, i.e. when setting the symbol in a bold context and find it another size compared to a non-bold context despite both being `\normalsize` (or whatever)...