# Special non-standard font sizes for different types

Tags: fonts, sectioning, pdftex, fontsize, sectsty

The more I read about fontsizes in LaTeX, the more confused I've become. I don't know how to meet my requirements, which are the following:

text = 11pt --> This works.

footnotes = 9pt --> This works.

section = 15pt --> ??

subsection = 13pt --> ??

These values are for Arial. I also got them for Times New Roman (each one increased by 1).
Concerning sections and subsections I read about scalefont, titlesec, sectsty,... but I could not work out a solution.

For example, if I use the following approach

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\scalefont{1.36}}
\subsectionfont{\scalefont{1.18}}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                                                    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Kapitel 1}
\subsection{Kapitel 1.1}
\end{document}
```

Latex prints a warning

> LaTex Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/cmr/bx/n' in size <19.584> not availabe
>
> size <20.74> substituted

How can I change this situation?

Comment: A general comment for all solutions: Your requirements are probaly PostScript points, while TeX points are a bit different. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4239/5763; you want to add `bp` to all font dimens to get PostScript points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rather unusual to be specifying things per document at this level but not particularly difficult: just copy the definition of `\section` from article class and change the font size to be the size requested. I'd note that Arial and Helvetica aren't really the same font.
The warning about font size was ignorable but if you load the fix-cm package it goes away.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                                                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont
%\Large % \@xivpt{18}
\fontsize{15}{20}%
\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont
%\large % \@xiipt{14}
\fontsize{13}{15}%
\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Kapitel 1}
\subsection{Kapitel 1.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested your code by generating pdf and copying the text to Word. The size matches, Word displays "F18" instead of Arial but a typing comparison is positive. It seems that yours is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the combination Times/Helvetica/Courier with proper scaling for the Helvetica font, you could use the combination

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
```

Using the short syntax for `\titleformat` from the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and `\fontsize{}{}\bfseries` you can adjust the font size for the sectional units. To change the font size for footnotes, you can use the etoolbox package to patch `\@footnotetext`:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}{}{}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{15}{18}\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{13}{15}\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot compile as "atoolbox" is not found.

Comment: @PWillms a typo; it is `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 4):

You need no computation and no `\scalefont` command: just tell LaTeX what you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

%\usepackage{mathptmx} % traditional Times package
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better Times package
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                                                 

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{15}{19}\sffamily}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{13}{16}\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\section{Kapitel 1}
\subsection{Kapitel 1.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why should anybody want section headers in Helvetica and text in Times is beyond my understanding. It reminds me of the Chinese all wearing the same suit.

Comment: That's probably a style guide dating from the 1970s which originated in the typewriter area.