# Is there an `ex` unit equivalent for the capital 'X' in LaTeX

Tags: characters, lengths, unit-of-measure

In LaTeX, the `ex` unit represents the height of a *lowercase* '**x**' in the current font.

Is there a length in LaTeX that represents the height of a capital '**X**'?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The information about 1ex is stored in the font; it is *usually* the height of a lowercase ‘x’, but it need not be necessarily.

You can access the height of an uppercase ‘X’ by

```
\fontcharht\font`X
```

A way for expressing lengths in this ‘unit of measure’ is

```
\newcommand{\eX}{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`X\relax}
```

so you can say something like

```
\vspace{1.2\eX}
```

or

```
\setlength{\mylen}{2\eX}
```

where `\mylen` has been allocated with `\newlength`.

Comment: Somehow off-topic comment-question (;-)): Which commands do define `1ex` to be (most times) the height of an `x` and which do deviate from them, and why?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See Johan's answer [Q:4239](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No command defines `1ex`; it's information stored in the font, it's the font designer's responsibility fixing it.

Comment: @egreg: I see -- I just thought, it is some command extracting some information from font and calculating `1ex` then.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your Answer and the background information! I am trying to do something like `\tikz[baseline=-.5\eX]` but it does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer When a font is loaded, TeX builds an internal array where the `\fontdimen` parameters defined in the font are stored. A font need have at least seven `\fontdimen` parameters, but may have more (math symbol fonts need 22, math extension fonts need 13). The x-height is `\fontdimen5`; when TeX scans `1ex` or `2.5ex`, it looks at the internal array for the fifth value; you could also say `2.5\fontdimen5\font` and achieve the same result.

Comment: @sergej This seems to work: `A\tikz[baseline=-1\eX]\draw(0,0)--(1,0);B`

Comment: @egreg It works with `\tikz[baseline=-.5\mylen]`...

Comment: @sergej Maybe a new question with a full (non)working example is better.

Comment: The `\fontcharht` is the case of the eTeX extension. It isn't icluded in standard TeX. The `\dimexpr` is the same case.

Comment: @egreg is using \relax here the right approach? that disallows using this unit as part of a skip specification for example

Comment: @FrankMittelbach The `\relax` is gobbled when `\dimexpr` is evaluated.

Comment: @egreg makes sense really - should have tried before making the comment :-(

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Probably a better choice would have been `\endexpr` instead of `\relax`, but I don't know the details of the implementation.