# Defining a replacement of a unicode character

Tags: xetex, pdftex, miktex, unicode

In my, automatically generated tex files there quite a few 'Replacement characters' 0xEFBFBD (see: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280).
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Here follows the "Replacement character": ï¿½ (EFBFBD).
\end{document}
```

(The display of the replacement character is depending on the chosen encoding, in this editor ANSI encoding I see ï¿½. When using vim I see �).

When running pdflatex (This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)), on files with these characters I get the error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ∩┐╜ (U+FFFD)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.7 Here follows the "Replacement character": ∩┐╜
                                                  (EFBFBD).
```

When running xelatex (This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)) a pdf is generated but nothing is shown:
[image]
In the answer from @StevenB.Segletes on the question [Unicode Replacement Character in Standard TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223194/unicode-replacement-character-in-standard-tex) a nice character is shown (I've rescaled it slightly for my needs in the my output code):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox,amssymb,graphicx,stackengine,xcolor}
\newlength{\CodeWidthChar}
\newlength{\CodeHeightChar}
\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
  \settowidth{\CodeWidthChar}{?}%
  \settoheight{\CodeHeightChar}{?}%
Here follows the "Replacement character": \ucr
\end{document}
```

Now I want automatically replace the 'Replacement Character' from my first example with this scaled defined character, but I don't succeed.
I tried with xelatex:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{�}{\ucr}
```

resulting in:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
                             {∩┐╜}{\ucr}
```

and:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{EFBFBD}{\ucr}
```

resulting in:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
                             {EFBFBD}{\ucr}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox,amssymb,graphicx,stackengine,xcolor}
\newlength{\CodeWidthChar}
\newlength{\CodeHeightChar}
\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{EFBFBD}{\ucr}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
```

%% edit:
    \settowidth{\CodeWidthChar}{?}%
    \settoheight{\CodeHeightChar}{?}%
%% end edit.
    Here follows the "Replacement character": � (EFBFBD).
    \end{document}

How to solve this problem (either in xelatex or pdflatex).

EDIT: added setting width and height in last code snippet.

Comment: Can U+FFFD be typeset to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With xelatex you can do this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{adjustbox,amssymb,graphicx,stackengine,xcolor}
\newlength{\CodeWidthChar}
\newlength{\CodeHeightChar}
\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{EFBFBD}{\ucr}
\catcode`\�=13
\def�{\ucr}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Here follows the "Replacement character": � (EFBFBD).
\end{document}
```

It doesn't work with lualatex, it complains about an invalid utf8 char.

With pdflatex you must declare the `FFFD` character (but you will have to correct the height and width in \ucr definition, it doesn't output anything for me with pdflatex):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox,amssymb,graphicx,stackengine,xcolor}
\newlength{\CodeWidthChar}
\newlength{\CodeHeightChar}
\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{XXX}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily \ucr
Here follows the "Replacement character": � (EFBFBD).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the width and height, I in the lat example on the DeclareUnicodeChar and therefor forgot / didn't see the missing of the setting (I will edit it into the question). The othe points I'll test.

Comment: @A.Donda The catcode? 13 is the number for "set active", so you should use it for everyone.

Comment: Sorry, just after I asked I found it in 1 s with Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code as provided by @UlrikeFischer works in case of pdflatex and xelatex. I combined it together so it works in both cases (and also added the missing settings of height and width):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox,amssymb,graphicx,stackengine,xcolor}
\newlength{\CodeWidthChar}
\newlength{\CodeHeightChar}
\def\ucr{\adjustbox{width=\CodeWidthChar,height=\CodeHeightChar}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\small ?}}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{\ucr}
\else
  \catcode`\�=13
  \def�{\ucr}
\fi

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\settowidth{\CodeWidthChar}{?}%
\settoheight{\CodeHeightChar}{?}%
Here follows the "Replacement character": � (EFBFBD).
\end{document}
```