# Create diamond with a dash in it

Tags: pdftex, symbols

I'm looking for how to create a diamond symbol with a dash that horizontally divides it. One like the following:

[image]

I found the `diamondminus` on `MnSymbol` package, but this new package is incompatible with other packages that I use such as `amssymb`.

Could you know how to create such a symbol?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427270/defining-a-replacement-of-a-unicode-character here a diamond (filled) with an questionmark is defined, maybe you can adjust it / have a starting point for your purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the `amssymb` package symbol you mentioned and added the dash, using `scalebox` (offered by `graphicx`) with different values for `x` and `y` to keep the thickness of the dash.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\hss#1\hss}}
\newcommand{\mydiamond}{%
  \sbox0{$\lozenge$}%
  \usebox0\kern-.5\wd0\clap{\raisebox{.1ex}{\scalebox{.7}[1]{$-$}}}\kern.5\wd0%
}

\begin{document}
\mydiamond

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you do not want white space between the two symbols, use `\scalebox{.80}[1]{$-$}`

Answer (score 6):

Two Approaches:

**Use existing `\Diamond` of `amssymb`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand\DDiamond{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.5pt}{\Diamond}{\scalebox{.75}[1]{$-$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$\DDiamond$ as created\par
$\Diamond$ is the amssymb version
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the cross-line to be a "dash" with space around it, reduce the value of `.75` in the `\scalebox` to, for example, `.6`:

[image]

**IMPORT JUST ONE `MnSymbol`**

Import **just** `\DDiamond` from `MnSymbol`.  Thus, it does not screw up the other definitions of `amssymb`.  I've declared it as `\mathrel` but you can change that.

I've set up convenient macros (between the `%%%%` delimiters) for importing stuff from `MnSymbol`.  Once those macros are set up (copied/pasted into your preamble), the import goes as follows:

```
\ImportFromMnSymbol{C}
\DeclareMnSymbol{\DDiamond}{\mathrel}{C}{120}
%\MnSymbolGlyphs{C}
```

`\MnSymbolGlyphs{}` shows the font table for MnSymbolA, B, C, etc, given the subset as the argument.  This is how to locate a glyph's subset and slot number.

`\ImportFromMnSymbol{}` sets up for importing symbols from the specified `MnSymbol` subset.

`\DeclareMnSymbol{<macroname>}{<math category>}{<subset>}{<slot>}` to grab the `MnSymbol` from the specified slot in the given subset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%%%
\def\MnSymbolGlyphs#1{% IF ONE NEEDS TO LOCATE GLYPHS
  \usepackage{MnSymbol,fonttable}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\fonttable{MnSymbol#110}}%
}
\def\ImportFromMnSymbol#1{%
  \DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbol#1}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbol#1}{m}{n}{
   <-6> MnSymbol#15
   <6-7> MnSymbol#16
   <7-8> MnSymbol#17
   <8-9> MnSymbol#18
   <9-10> MnSymbol#19
   <10-12> MnSymbol#110
   <12-> MnSymbol#112}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbol#1}{b}{n}{
   <-6> MnSymbol#1-Bold5
   <6-7> MnSymbol#1-Bold6
   <7-8> MnSymbol#1-Bold7
   <8-9> MnSymbol#1-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbol#1-Bold9
   <10-12> MnSymbol#1-Bold10
   <12-> MnSymbol#1-Bold12}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{MnSy#1} {U} {MnSymbol#1}{m}{n}
}
\newcommand\DeclareMnSymbol[4]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{MnSy#3}{#4}}
%%%%
\ImportFromMnSymbol{C}
\DeclareMnSymbol{\DDiamond}{\mathrel}{C}{120}
%\MnSymbolGlyphs{C}
\begin{document}
$\DDiamond$ as imported from MnSymbol\par
$A \DDiamond B\quad\scriptstyle A \DDiamond B\quad\scriptscriptstyle A \DDiamond B$

$\Diamond$ is still the amssymb version
\end{document}
```

[image]