# Vertical Centered Horizontal Line on the same line as text?

Tags: alignment, vertical, awesome-cv

I'm trying to modify [awesome cv](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) so that the horizontal line is centered vertically in the line. 
[image: trying to center horizontal line vertically]

The relevant line of code in [awesome-cv.cls](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls) is the following declaration:

`\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}`

I've read another answer that says to use depth to do it, but after playing with it for a while I just can't seem to get it right. Please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Center text between horizontal lines extending to the margin on either side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243651/69818).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To also specify the depth you can add `\@depth<some length>` right after `\@height#1` (or right before, the order does not matter). 
A version of `\vhrulefill` that also lets you specify the depth as `#2` would thus be:

```
\makeatletter %% <- change @ so that it can be used in command sequences
\def\myrulefill#1#2{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\@depth#2\hfill \kern\z@}
\makeatother  %% <- change @ back
```

Once you have defined this, you can produce a line whose top is raised `<top` from the baseline and whose bottom is raised `<bottom>` with `\myrulefill{<top>}{-<bottom>}`. Note the minus sign, which is necessary because the depth of a rule is actually the distance it extends *below* the baseline.

You do not specify what you mean by "centred", but I can think of at least three possibilities:

1. **Centred w.r.t. the capital letter X**

   This seems to be what your picture indicates. 
   You can produce such a line of thickness `#1` with:

   ```
   \newcommand*\crulefill[1]{\myrulefill
       {\dimexpr(\fontcharht\font`X+#1)/2}{\dimexpr(-\fontcharht\font`X+#1)/2}}
   ```

   I'm using `\fontcharht` to obtain the height of the letter `X` ([like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185792/156366)) in the current font and `\dimexpr` to do computations with dimensions ([like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185792/156366)).
2. **Centred w.r.t. the lowercase letter x**

   The letter x has a height of `1ex`, so if this is what you want you can centre your rule at `.5ex` using:

   ```
   \renewcommand*\crulefill[1]{\myrulefill{\dimexpr(1ex+#1)/2}{\dimexpr(-1ex+#1)/2}}
   ```
3. **Centred w.r.t. the math axis**

   The math axis is the imaginary line on which mathematical operators like `+`, `-`, `*` and for instance `\rightarrow` and the bar in fractions are centred.
   For Computer Modern, the math axis is positioned slightly higher than `.5ex` above the baseline.
   Here's how you can get a rule centred on the math axis:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand*\crulefill[1]{%
     \settoheight\@tempdima{$\m@th\vcenter{}$}%
     \myrulefill{\dimexpr\@tempdima+#1/2}{\dimexpr-\@tempdima+#1/2}%
   }
   \makeatother
   ```

   This uses `\vcenter{}` to create an empty box centred on the math axis and stores its height in the scratch register `\@tempdima` using `\settoheight`.f

(The `%` at the end of some lines are there for reasons explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/156366) by the way.)

### Demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter %% <- change @ so that it can be used in command sequences
\def\myrulefill#1#2{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\@depth#2\hfill \kern\z@}
\makeatother %% <- change @ back

\begin{document}

% ================================== %
%  Centred at half the height of X:  %
% ================================== %
\newcommand*\crulefill[1]{\myrulefill
  {\dimexpr(\fontcharht\font`X+#1)/2}{\dimexpr(-\fontcharht\font`X+#1)/2}}

X \crulefill{1pt} $\leftarrow$ centred w.r.t.\@ X.

% ================================== %
%  Centred at half the height of x:  %
% ================================== %
\renewcommand*\crulefill[1]{\myrulefill{\dimexpr(1ex+#1)/2}{\dimexpr(-1ex+#1)/2}}

x \crulefill{1pt} $\leftarrow$ centred w.r.t.\@ x.

% =========================== %
%  Centred on the math axis:  %
%  =========================== %

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\crulefill[1]{%
  \settoheight\@tempdima{$\m@th\vcenter{}$}%
  \myrulefill{\dimexpr\@tempdima+#1/2}{\dimexpr-\@tempdima+#1/2}%
}
\makeatother

$+$ \crulefill{1pt} $\leftarrow$ centred w.r.t.\@ math axis.

\end{document}
```

[image]