# How to draw three tikz circles that align to the west

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I tried to draw three circles aligned together.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, minimum size=8cm, draw, fill=pink,anchor=west] (a) {ppou};
\node[circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, fill=green,  anchor=west] (b) {oooo};
 
\node[circle, minimum size=3.6cm, draw, fill=orange, anchor=west] (c) {Inner Market};

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, } ] (0:7) arc (30:-70:5.5cm); 
\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = Private Market } ] (0:4.5) arc (-0:-60:4.6cm);

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = Total Market}] (0:6.7) arc (0:-90:6cm); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How could I better align the text in the outer and middle circle to make it looks better?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

Comment: Does the text need to be curved? If you use two lines, you can use horizontal text which will be much more comfortable to read https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu9Cl.png

Comment: I agree with @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Don't be fancy, be legible. The fancy solution requires you to create an arc that has symmetry around 0°, i.e. `(-90:<radius>) arc[start angle=-90, delta angle=180, radius=<radius>]`.

Comment: You can find [similar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675092) and answers by searching this site for Euler diagrams or even the `text along path` decoration itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It looks much better than my original one. Could you please post the latex code to implement it? I am not familiar with the tikz package. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz,

Comment: @VictorLi You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two more alternatives for you:

- left: putting two (or three) more nodes as labels
- right: same idea, but anchored south (i.e. using same amount of space)

[image: results]

Did some **refactoring** wrt styles, also to simplify code lines:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    crc/.style={circle,anchor=west,draw},
    lbl/.style={align=center},
    ]
    % ~~~ cicles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[crc, minimum size=8cm, fill=pink]     (a) {};
...
```

To place the **labels**, just shift them wrt to the colored nodes, either using cartesian or polar notation:

```
    % ... two alternatives ...........
    \node[yshift=33mm]  at (a)                  {Total Market};
    \node[lbl]          at ([shift=(30:3.0)] a) {Total\\Market};
```

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    crc/.style={circle,anchor=west,draw},
    lbl/.style={align=center},
    ]
    % ~~~ cicles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[crc, minimum size=8cm, fill=pink]     (a) {};
    \node[crc, minimum size=6cm, fill=green,]   (b) {};
    \node[crc, minimum size=3.6cm, fill=orange] (c) {Inner Market};
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[yshift=22mm]  at (b)                  {Private Market};
    % ... two alternatives ...........
    \node[yshift=33mm]  at (a)                  {Total Market};
    \node[lbl]          at ([shift=(30:3.0)] a) {Total\\Market};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    crc/.style={circle,anchor=south,draw},
    %lbl/.style={align=center},
    ]
    % ~~~ cicles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[crc, minimum size=8cm, fill=pink]     (a) {};
    \node[crc, minimum size=6cm, fill=green,]   (b) {};
    \node[crc, minimum size=3.6cm, fill=orange] (c) {Inner Market};
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[yshift=16mm]  at (b)                  {Private Market};
    \node[yshift=27mm]  at (a)                  {Total Market};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me many alternatives. I learned a lot from your code. Victor

Answer (score 2):

An example of short code where circle styles has three parameters:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{circle, draw, anchor=west, minimum size=#1, fill=#2,
                           label = {[text width=4em, align=left, anchor=east]east:#3},
                           node contents={}},
                        ]
\node[C=6cm/pink/Total Market];
\node[C=4cm/green/Private Market];
\node[C=2cm/orange/Inner Market];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, the text will be more comfortable to read if it is horizontal. For the second and third circle, you can split it over two lines to have enough room. For the first circle I would keep your text as it is, so the circle does not look too empty:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, minimum size=8cm, draw, fill=pink,anchor=west] (a) {ppou};
\node[circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, fill=green,anchor=west] (b) {oooo};
\node[circle, minimum size=3.6cm, draw, fill=orange, anchor=west] (c) {Inner Market};

\node[text width=2cm,align=center] at (4.75cm,0) {Private Market};
\node[text width=2cm,align=center] at (7cm,0) {Total Market};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is cleaner than mine, and it solves my problem. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @VictorLi You're welcome!