# I want a double space between my paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I want double spacing between my lines so I used this:

\doublespacing

Now I also want a single double space between my paragraphs, what should I do in that case?

If I didn't change anything in my tex file, I would get a sort of a double double space (4 spaces). I can't tell that for sure, because I do not know how to measure a double space in tex file, but I am giving an approximation. Thus, to cut this short, if I want one double space between my paragraphs, what should I do?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: Maybe you want to change `\parskip`

Comment: Welcome! By default, the spacing between paragraphs is the same as that between lines. Since this seems to be what you want, you shouldn't have to do anything. If that's not what you get, something in your code is responsible. What exactly nobody can really say without knowing the code. If you do wish to change `\parskip` (and I've misunderstood your question), then don't change it directly. Load **parskip** if using a standard class, at least. (Other classes may have better options.) This is assuming you are using LaTeX which we can't tell as you've not told us or shown us.

Comment: BTW, in LaTeX there is really no such thing a double spacing, just some spaces are bigger than others.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `setspace` and `parskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\parindent=1.5em % or whatever you need
\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thanks for your answer! What's 1.5em? Is it equivalent to a double space? Also what does a \kant[1-2] do?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics `1.5em` is (roughly) 1.5 times the width of an 'm' in the current font, so 15pt in a 10pt font. (The notion of a "double space" isn't very clear with any proportional spaced font.)  It's what the standard paragraph indent is set to in the standard classes.  See [Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4239) and [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260) for more details.  `\kant[1-2]` just produces the first 2 paragraphs of the `kantlipsum` dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the trick to precise control over the space between lines is to use \vspace.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\vspace{4mm}
\lipsum[3]
\vspace{8mm}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```