# How to print various type-related metrics

Tags: unit-of-measure

In the answer by @Johan_E to [Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97970/36296), there are useful charts showing the size, in points, of 1em, the width of an `M`, 1ex, and the height of an `x`.  How can I produce such a chart?  Most useful would be an example of how to produce the first row to illustrate the measurement commands and/or one other row (say bf, it) to illustrate how the font selection is done.  (I know how to get a bf,it `M`, but how do I get a bf,it `1em`?)

I am forever try to scale zlmtt to match my font, zooming in on a pdf viewer screen and eye-balling it.  Having actual measurements would make such scaling much easier.

Employing the advice of @jfbu in the comment below, I have the following extracted from the xintools loop, which seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\oneem{}
\newcommand\oneex{}
\newcommand\Mwidth{}
\newcommand\xheight{}
\newcommand\xwidth{}
\newcommand\xdepth{}

\begin{document}
\edef\oneem{\the\dimexpr 1em\relax}%
\edef\oneex{\the\dimexpr 1ex\relax}%
\setbox0\hbox{M}%
\edef\Mwidth{\the\wd0}%
\setbox0\hbox{x}%
\edef\xheight{\the\ht0}%
\edef\xwidth{\the\wd0}%
\edef\xdepth{\the\dp0}%
%
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
  font & 1em    & M-width & 1ex    & x-height & x-width & x-depth \\
  rm   & \oneem & \Mwidth & \oneex & \xheight & \xwidth & \xdepth
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should tell how you scale `zlmtt`; there's probably some automatic method to find the correct factor without looking at tables or eyeballing.

Comment: @dedded You can directly link to the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97970/36296

Comment: @egreg, I'd still like to know the answer to this question (as it's more general), but automatic scaling to equivalent x-heights would be the best solution for (most of?) my use cases.  I currently scale with `\usepackage[scale=x.x]{zlmtt}, where x.x is determined by trial-and-error.  @samcarter, thank you, I've edited the question.  How did you determine the link to the answer?

Comment: well, LaTeX makes public only a subset of the underlying TeX language. Among the things hidden to the average user are the token list registers and variables and, relevant here, the `\edef` primitive. LaTeX's `\newcommand` is a wrapper for `\def`, but there is no one for `\edef`. Replace all your `\renewcommand`'s by `\edef`'s and it should work. By the way, do leave the `\newcommand` in the preamble, to check that nothing defined in packages is overwritten. I should have chosen longer names, like `\heightofletterx`. (my answer uses `\xdef` which is  `\global\edef`, needed due to cell scope).

Comment: "I should have chosen longer names, like `\heightofletterx`"  I like the emacs convention of a `my` prefix when I want to avoid collisions with my own personal code and published code, which helps preserve brevity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\WithFont [4]{%
   \csname text#1\endcsname {%
      \csname text#3\endcsname {%
         \csname text#2\endcsname {#4}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
\Large\textbf{Computer Modern fonts (pdf\LaTeX) [10pt]}\\
\small
Selected using \detokenize{\textA{\textB{\textC{(some text)}}}},\\
with A in \detokenize{{rm, sf, tt}}; B in \detokenize{{md, bf}}; C in
\detokenize{{up, it, sl, sc}}\\
  \begin{tabular}{*{9}{l}}
    \bf Font&\bf 1em&&\bf M-width&\bf 1ex&&\bf x-height&\bf x-width&\bf x-depth\\
\hline
\xintForpair #1#2 in {(Roman,rm), (Sans,sf), (Typewriter,tt)} \do
{%
\xintFor #3 in {up, it, sl, sc}\do
  {%
    \xintFor #4 in {md, bf}\do
    {%
      \WithFont {#2}{#3}{#4}{#1, #3, #4\normalsize
                             \xdef\oneem{\the\dimexpr 1em\relax}%
                             \xdef\oneex{\the\dimexpr 1ex\relax}%
                             \setbox0\hbox{M}\xdef\Mwidth{\the\wd0}%
                             \setbox0\hbox{x}\xdef\xheight{\the\ht0}%
                                             \xdef\xwidth{\the\wd0}%
                                             \xdef\xdepth{\the\dp0}}%
      &\oneem&\WithFont{#2}{#3}{#4}{\normalsize\strut M}&\Mwidth
      &\oneex&\WithFont{#2}{#3}{#4}{\normalsize x}&\xheight&\xwidth&\xdepth
     \\
     }%
   }\hline
}\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(`\normalsize` added in edit, because all the table was produced earlier under `\small` regime, including computation of dimensions).

> [image]

---

Attention that in the table above, there are a number of font substitutions going on :

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sc' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/it' tried instead on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/it' tried instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmtt/bx/n' instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sl' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sl' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmtt/bx/n' instead on input line 55.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sc' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/sc' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 55.
```

I thought about for example drawing a strike-through  line across the full row, but doing this automatically has complications. As this is not the main focus of the OP, I just leave standing as is.

---

For automatic determination, shamelessly copying over egreg's answer into another syntax. Notice that `xinttools` used above is a separate package from `xintfrac` used below.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{zlmtt}
\usepackage{xintfrac}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scalezlmtt}[2][1]{%
   {\setbox0\hbox{\normalfont #2}%
    \setbox2\hbox{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont #2}%
    \xdef\zlmtt@scale {\xintPFloat {\xintMul{#1}{\ht0/\ht2}}}%
    \typeout{zlmtt scaling factor: \zlmtt@scale}% 
   }%
}%
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\scalezlmtt[.9]{a}}

\begin{document}

TT font scaled to 90\% lowercase: A\texttt{A}a\texttt{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will find in the log:

```
zlmtt scaling factor: 0.9143980556305698
```

This differs in the last digit from l3fp's calculation, but that's not so much typographically relevant...

(try it with `\xintPFloat [32]...` for example if you want more --irrelevant-- digits, well ok I did it:

```
zlmtt scaling factor: 0.91439805563056980826357007831488
```

I would really need a scaling factor of `0.1` to hide my irrelevant toying here)

Comment: Well, _that's_ going to take some study!  Thank you, I'm sure I'll have some follow-up questions.

Comment: Ugh, maybe I declared victory too soon.  My results are quite similar to Johan_E's original, as I said, but larger than yours.  I chalked it up to possible differences in our systems.  But when I run _your_ code, I get your results.  (I'm only looking at the first row, and I also generated a bfseries row.)  Now I'm not sure which numbers to believe.

Comment: I think the `\small` is still in effect in your loop when the font is sampled.

Comment: @dedded yes good point. That was sort of on purpose but the [10pt] is then inadequate. I thought I needed the small to fit the table on the page. ... well ok I will fix it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: sorry about the generated confusion ...

Comment: No problem, I don't need to literally generate a table, I wanted to understand how to get the values.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will do one more update related to the fact that (mainly for typewriter) most things are actually not available, and LaTeX has subsituted fonts.

Answer (score 4):

I can offer a macro for deciding the scale factor as automatically as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zlmtt}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\scalezlmtt}{O{1}m}
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \normalfont #2 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont #2 }
  \tl_set:cx { zlmtt@scale }
   {
    \fp_eval:n
     {
      #1 *
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box } /
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_ht:N \l_tmpb_box }
     }
   }
  \typeout{ zlmtt~scaling:~\tl_use:c { zlmtt@scale } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{\scalezlmtt{A}}

\begin{document}

TT font scaled to uppercase: A\texttt{A}a\texttt{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the call to `\scalezlmtt{a}`,

```
\AtBeginDocument{\scalezlmtt{a}}

\begin{document}

TT font scaled to lowercase: A\texttt{A}a\texttt{a}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

There's also a “correction factor”

```
\AtBeginDocument{\scalezlmtt[.9]{a}}

\begin{document}

TT font scaled to 90\% lowercase: A\texttt{A}a\texttt{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This should be flexible enough for avoiding lookups in tables or eyeballing. By doing the job `\AtBeginDocument`, the call to `\normalfont` will be the right one. Just load other font packages before this instruction, because some of them do actions at begin document too.

The trick is to use `lmtt` for the measurement, so this doesn't yet trigger the loading of `<encoding>zlmtt.fd`.

In the log file you'll see something like

```
zlmtt scaling: 0.9143980556305699
```

(this is the value used for the last example) and you may be wanting to round it and use in the package option once you're sure it will suit you.