# What unit-of-measure for distances or other aspects (width, height,..) should be used inside Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, unit-of-measure

I was wondering if it is just a question of someones own opionion or is there a clear superior way of using unit-of-measure such as

- pt,
- px,
- cm,
- ex,
- ...

when drawing a picture or setting the tikzstyles? Maybe some way is more "dynamic" or have other advantages?

Comment: If you don't specify a unit, Ti*k*Z assumes it's in centimetres. After that, they are all converted to `sp` (scaled points) inside TeX, so I guess the answer is "the one you need or the one you like"

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Not really. Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2]
   \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` to see that the argument of `xshift` is interpreted as points whereas the circle radii are interpreted as `cm`. Actually, most of the more low-level stuff used points rather than centimeters.

Comment: @marmot Ooh, this is new for me... This seems messy :P But either way, everything is converted using the appropriate scale factor.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, *if* you specify the units. Again, I think that the "default" units for Ti*k*Z are points, not centimeters. What I mean by that is that internally Ti*k*Z is using points.

Comment: @marmot I think that's because TeX defaults everything to points. If you say `\the\dimexpr1cm` you'll get it converted to `pt`.

Comment: The default for inner sep is .333em, so it depends.

Comment: I really think that all relevant information is contained in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex?rq=1). Ti*k*Z is IMO not special, it just comes with very nice means to convert lengths. Try e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylen}{1cm+2pt+3ex}`, you'll get the sum of the three dimensions in points. (Of course, `\mylen` here is no length, just a macro, in this case just `43.36937`, which specifies the distance in points.)