# Coloring the numbers of the theorems

Tags: numbering, newtheorem

Can anyone please help me to do how to become blue the number 1.12? [image: number]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add an example document to the question that reproduces the above output

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution with declaring a new `theoremstyle`, using the documentation of `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{note}% 
{3pt}%Space above
{3pt}%Space below
{}%Body font
{}%Indent amount
{}%Theorem head font
{.}%Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}%Space after theorem head
{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{thm}{Exemplo}
\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked fine here! But, considering that you used commands that I have never seen before, please provide me more details about the following: 1)  Why did you put note in "\newtheoremstyle{note}"?. 2) What do "{}%Body font" and
"{}%Indent amount" mean? 3) Can I put the dot in blue in
"{.}%Punctuation after theorem head". 4) Can I replace "em" for "cm" in  "{.5em}" ?

Comment: @MarcosPaulo 1) "note" is just a unique identifier for the theorem style being declared; another name would also work, 2) these are both arguments for `\newtheoremstyle`, you may want to have a look at the the [amsthm usage guide](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), 3) yeah, `{\textblue{.}}` would do that, 4) you could use `cm` instead, but the advantage of `em` as a unit is that it scales with the font size (see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex?s=4|49.0769)).